# In this program of different operation on matrix the saddlepoint() function if not producing correct output. Why?

Tags: c, matrix

I wrote this program to perform different operations on matrix using dynamic allocation, the function for finding the saddle point is not producing the correct output. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int** inputmatrix(int **a,int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("\n Input the Elements of the Matrix :");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int** add(int **a, int **b, int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
int** multiplication(int** a, int **b, int r1, int c1, int c2)
{
    int **c,i,j,k;
    c = (int**)malloc(r1*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
    {
        c[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for(k=0; k<c1; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int minval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, min;
    min = a[r][0];
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        if(a[r][i]<min)
        {
            min = a[r][i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int maxval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, max;
    max = a[0][c];
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        if(a[i][c] > max )
        {
            max = a[i][c];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void saddlepoint(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, rpos, cpos, flag = 0,sp;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] == minval(a, i, j) && a[i][j] == maxval(a, i, j))
            {
                sp = a[i][j];
                flag = 1;
                rpos = i;
                cpos = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        printf("\n The Saddle point of the Matrix is found at position (%d,%d) value is %d ", rpos, cpos,sp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n There is no saddle point in the Matrix ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **a, **b,r1,c1,r2,c2, i,j,ch;
    int **c;
    printf("\n enter your choice : \n1.Addition \n2.Multiplication \n3.Saddle Point \n4. Magic Square \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    printf("\n enter the oder of matrix A :");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
                printf("\n enter the oder of matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
                if(r1==r2 && c1==c2)
                {
                    b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                    a = add(a,b,r1,c1);
                    printf("\n the result of the addition of matrices is :");
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0;j<c1; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n these matrices can't be added ");
                }
                break;
        case 2 :
                printf("\n Enter the Order of Matrix B :");
                scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
                b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                if(c1 == r2)
                {


                    c = multiplication(a, b, r1, c1, r2);
                    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n Sorry, These Matrices Can't be Multiplied ");
                }
                break;
        case 3 : saddlepoint(a,r1,c1);
                break;
        default : printf("\n Sorry, This is a Wrong Choice ");
            }
    return 0;
}
```

please let me know any logical error in my `saddlepoint()` function.

```
int minval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, min;
    min = a[r][0];
    for(i=0; i<c; i++)
    {
        if(a[r][i]<min)
        {
            min = a[r][i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int maxval(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, max;
    max = a[0][c];
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        if(a[i][c] > max )
        {
            max = a[i][c];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

void saddlepoint(int **a, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j, rpos, cpos, flag = 0,sp;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] == minval(a, i, j) && a[i][j] == maxval(a, i, j))
            {
                sp = a[i][j];
                flag = 1;
                rpos = i;
                cpos = j;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        printf("\n The Saddle point of the Matrix is found at position (%d,%d) value is %d ", rpos, cpos,sp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n There is no saddle point in the Matrix ");
    }
}
```

Here in the saddlepoint() funtion i am checking that if any element of the 2D matrix is minimum in the row and simultaneously the maximum in the column , then that will be the saddle point. For this i'm calling the minval() and maxval() functions in the if condition of saddlepoint() fuction.

example of output : -
 enter your choice : 
1.Addition 
2.Multiplication 
3.Saddle Point 
4. Magic Square 
3

enter the oder of matrix A :3
3

Input the Elements of the Matrix :1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

The Saddle point of the Matrix is found at position (0,0) value is 1 amit@amit-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: `if(flag = 1)` assigns 1 to `flag`. You probably want `if(flag == 1)` which compares 1 and `flag`. And next time, post your expected output and the output you see along with your inputs (if any). Also, explain what your code does and most importantly, Post a [mcve]

Comment: ok, done whatever you said.. still the output for every case isThe Saddle point of the Matrix is found at position (0,0) value is "the element entered at first position"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // error #1: was missing this; required for malloc()

int** inputmatrix(int** a, int r, int c ) {

    int i,j;

    a = (int**)malloc(r*sizeof(int*)); // error #2: didn't have *
    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i) a[i] = (int*)malloc(c*sizeof(int)); // error #3: had i < c, error #4: didn't have c*
    printf("\n input the elements of the matrix : ");
    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    return a;

} // end inputmatrix()

int** add(int** a, int** b, int r, int c ) {

    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
            a[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
    return a;

} // end add()

int** multiplication(int** a, int** b, int r1, int c1, int c2 ) {

    int **c,i,j,k;

    c = (int**)malloc(r1*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < r1; ++i) c[i] = (int*)malloc(c2*sizeof(int)); // error #5: had i < c2, error #6: didn't have c2*
    for (i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
            c[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < c1; ++k) c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
        } // end for
    } // end for
    return c;

} // end multiplication()

int min_r(int** a, int r, int c ) { // suggestion: clarify the purpose of this function by renaming and adding comment: // min for row r across all columns 0:c-1

    int i,min;

    min = a[r][0];
    for (i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        if (a[r][i] < min)
            min = a[r][i];
    return min;

} // end min_r()

int max_c(int** a, int r, int c ) { // suggestion: clarify the purpose of this function by renaming and adding comment: // max for column c across all rows 0:r-1

    int i,max;

    max = a[0][c];
    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i)
        if (a[i][c] > max)
            max = a[i][c];
    return max;

} // end max_c()

void saddlepoint(int** a, int r, int c ) {

    int i,j,rpos,cpos,flag = 0,sp;

    for (i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
            if (a[i][j] == min_r(a,i,c) && a[i][j] == max_c(a,r,j)) { // error #7: was passing j instead of c into min_r(), error #8: was passing i instead of r into max_c()
                sp = a[i][j];
                flag = 1;
                rpos = i;
                cpos = j;
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end for
    if (flag == 1) // error #9: had flag = 1
        printf("\n the saddle point of the matrix is found at position (%d,%d) value is %d ",rpos,cpos,sp);
    else
        printf("\n there is no saddle point in the matrix ");

} // end saddlepoint()

int main(void) {

    int **a,**b,r1,c1,r2,c2,i,j,ch;
    int **c;

    printf("\n enter your choice : \n1. addition \n2. multiplication \n3. saddle point \n4. magic square \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    printf("\n enter the order of matrix A : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    a = inputmatrix(a,r1,c1);

    switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            printf("\n enter the order of matrix B : ");
            scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
            if (r1 == r2 && c1 == c2) {
                b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
                a = add(a,b,r1,c1);
                printf("\n the result of the addition of matrices is : ");
                for (i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
                    printf("\n");
                    for (j = 0; j < c1; ++j)
                        printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
                } // end for
            } else {
                printf("\n these matrices can't be added ");
            } // end if
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n enter the order of matrix B : ");
            scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
            b = inputmatrix(b,r2,c2);
            if (c1 == r2) {
                c = multiplication(a,b,r1,c1,r2);
                for (i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
                    printf("\n");
                    for (j = 0; j < c2; ++j)
                        printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                } // end for
            } else {
                printf("\n these matrices can't be multiplied ");
            } // end if
            break;
        case 3:
            saddlepoint(a,r1,c1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n this is a wrong choice ");
    } // end switch

    return 0;

} // end main()
```

Demo:

```
gcc a.c -o a;
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 1
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
##  enter the order of matrix B : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 7 8 9 10 11 12
##
##  the result of the addition of matrices is :
## 8 10
## 12  14
## 16  18
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 1
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 1 1
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 3
##
##  enter the order of matrix B : 2 1
##
##  these matrices can't be added
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 2
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
##  enter the order of matrix B : 2 1
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 10 20
##
## 50
## 110
## 170
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 2
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
##  enter the order of matrix B : 1 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2
##
##  these matrices can't be multiplied
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 3
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2 3 4 5 6
##
##  the saddle point of the matrix is found at position (2,0) value is 5
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 3
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 6 5 4 3 2 1
##
##  the saddle point of the matrix is found at position (0,1) value is 5
./a;
##
##  enter your choice :
## 1. addition
## 2. multiplication
## 3. saddle point
## 4. magic square
## 3
##
##  enter the order of matrix A : 3 2
##
##  input the elements of the matrix : 1 2 2 1 1 2
##
##  there is no saddle point in the matrix
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm sure the answer is just peachy, but hardly informative if I must `diff` two versions of the code to attempt to figure out what the problem, or solution was. How about a bit of explanation to make the answer more informative?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ya sure, as you wish.